# Paging Style of a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to change the paging style of a SharePoint list. Currently it is displayed as 
1-30. I want every page to be displayed so that the user can go directly to a any page.
Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Please tag the target SharePoint version

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any OOTB solution, but this could be solved with JavaScript.

1. Get list item count with JSOM or REST.
2. Add links/buttons to page for each page (item count / items per page).
3. On page link/button click refresh browser page with correct page number.

Refresh would look like this:

```
function refresh(page) {
  page = page * 30;
  var firstRow = page + 1;
  var query = "?Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + page + "&PageFirstRow=" + firstRow;
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to achieve this.

You need to custom develop and use `SPGridView` control

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/03/23/adding-paging-to-spgridview-when-using-custom-data-sources.aspx